# Is it possible to create an SSO user using terraform - AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, single-sign-on, terraform-provider-aws

Please let me know Is it possible to create an SSO user using Terraform in AWS. I could see that doc for the creation of AWS SSO permission sets and assignment to AWS SSO entities and AWS Accounts. but could not found any doc for creating an SSO user using terraform.

Comment: See https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/18812. It looks like it's not supported (yet).

Comment: It looks like this feature will be available at some point this year at least.

Comment: @DanielViglione Do you have a source for this prediction?

Answer (score 3):

It is now available with `identitystore_user`: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/identitystore_user

(in case it helps other like me who arrived here before finding the ressource)